# How does Nodejs performance scale when using http.request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm writing an application that makes heavy use of the http.request method.

In particular, I've found that sending 16+ ~30kb requests simultaneously **really** bogs down a Nodejs instance on a 512mb RAM machine.

I'm wondering if this is to be expected, or if Nodejs is just the wrong platform for outbound requests.

Comment: Please post code and quantify statements like "really bogs down a machine" (cpu load?, memory usage? file handles?).

Comment: I'd prefer to not post the code, but the CPU load hangs around 30-60%, memory usage is ~700mb of virtual, and the number of open sockets shouldn't exceed 16 per job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this behavior seems perfectly reasonable.

I would be more concerned if it was doing the work you described without any noticeable load on the system (in which case it would take a very long time).  Remember that node is just an evented I/O runtime, so you can have faith that it is scheduling your I/O requests (about) as quickly as the underlying system can, hence it's using the system to it's (nearly) maximum potential, hence the system being "really bogged down".

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case; thanks for the clarification! 

I'm assuming then that Node performance should scale nicely with server costs? :D

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should be aware of is the fact that http.request does not create a new socket for each call. Each request occurs on an object called an "agent" which contains a pool of up to 5 sockets. If you are using the v0.6 branch, then you can up this limit by using.

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity
```

Try that and see if it helps

Comment: Already did, with not much of a performance boost. :-/ Thanks though!